# xsltproc output doesn't append to file in bash for loop

Tags: bash, xslt, find

I was trying to redirect/append my output to a text file, but it seems for some reason, the xsltproc statement is never executed.
File names are displayed for "echo $xml_file" but not once the xsltproc statement is executed. can't figure out why

```
#!/bin/bash
for xml_file in $(find /directory/test/* -name '*.xml'); do
   echo $xml_file
   xsltproc indi.xsl $xml_file >> out.txt
done
```

Comment: See entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Also, you're better off putting a `>out.txt` on the outside of the loop, not a `>>out.txt` on the inside -- what you're doing now re-opens the output file on every iteration, rather than just opening it once and leaving it open for the whole loop. Put a `>&2` on your `echo "$xml_file"` (and yes, the quotes are needed to ensure correctness!) to prevent it from being appended to that file.

Comment: ...also, you need quotes on the `"$xml_file"` on the xlstproc command line as well to ensure correct behavior with interesting filenames or non-default IFS values. See also http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: BTW, use `set -x` or `bash -x yourscript` to see exactly what is and isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
for xml_file in ~/xslt-test/*.xml
do
        xsltproc -o text.txt test.xsl $xml_file
        cat text.txt >> out.txt
done
```

May be it help you.

Comment: Quotes! `"$xml_file"`, or you'll have unfortunate behavior with filenames containing spaces.

Comment: That said, this is much better than the OP's code in terms of its globbing practices (though not entirely equivalent, inasmuch as it doesn't recurse).

Comment: BTW, the man page for xsltproc is *entirely explicit* that the default output is to stdout, so there's no need to specify a file.

Answer (score 0):

The below tells `find` to directly invoke `xsltproc` once per file found, and concatenates all the results into a single `out.txt` file (opening that output file only once, not once per xsltproc instance, thus using `>` rather than `>>`):

```
find /directory/test \
  -name '*.xml' \
  -exec xsltproc indi.xsl '{}' ';' \
  >out.txt
```